# How to Set Android WebView BaseURL to application private files

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to know how can I set BaseURL when using `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL()` method to applications private files. I mean the file that we access them using `context.openFileOutput(filepath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` or `context.openFileInput(filepath)`.
I hope it is possible to do such thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
  mWebView.loadUrl("file:///data/data/<package_name>/files/example.html");
```

or

**Open file as inputstream then convert that input stream to string and pass it to loaddataWithBaseURL**

```
FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput ("your internal storage file name"); 

int len = 0, ch; 
StringBuffer source = new StringBuffer(); 
// read the file char by char 
while( (ch = fin.read()) != -1)     
source.append((char)ch); 
fIn.close(); 

mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,source,"text/html","UTF-8","about:blank");
```